How do I to update the name and logo of my SPL token?
I am new to solana programming and I just minted some tokens. I would like to update the name and logo.
Can someone help with the next steps? Where do we store the metadata?
Thanks in advance.

Welcome to Solana Stack Exchange! I've updated the title of your question to reflect main the question you're asking. Regarding Raydium, please ask in a separate question, that way others users can be helped with that answer.

The first step is to make sure that you minted the tokens with the isMutable flag set to true else the process below will not work.
To update the image you will need to update the entire off-chain metadata contained in the URI. If you are using a decentralized solution like ipfs, it'll be impossible to update the data of the hash and you'll have to read that data and create new hash.
Here's how to do so using UMI
import {
    createGenericFile,
    keypairIdentity,
    publicKey,
    Umi,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import {
    clusterApiUrl,
    Connection,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
    fetchMetadataFromSeeds,
    findMasterEditionPda,
    mplTokenMetadata,
    updateV1,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";
import fs, { readFileSync } from "fs";
import path from "path";

export const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

const umi = createUmi(connection);

export const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from("UPDATE WITH SECRET KEY"));

umi.use(keypairIdentity(keypair)).use(mplTokenMetadata());

export function uint8FileData(pathName: string): Uint8Array {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, pathName);

    const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    return data;
}

async function updateSPLTokenMD() {
    const mint = publicKey(""); // update with mint address
    const onChainMetadata = await fetchMetadataFromSeeds(umi, { mint });

    const newName = "Updated Asset Name";

    const offChainMetadata = await (await fetch(onChainMetadata.uri)).json();

    const filePath = "<PATH TO YOUR IMAGE FILE>"; // update this appropriately
    let fileData = uint8FileData(filePath);
    let file = createGenericFile(fileData, filePath, {
        contentType: "image/jpeg", // update the file MIME type if different
    });

    const [image] = await umi.uploader.upload([file]);
    const uri = await umi.uploader.uploadJson({
        ...offChainMetadata,
        image,
        name: newName,
    });

    await updateV1(umi, {
        mint,
        authority: umi.identity,
        data: { ...onChainMetadata, name: newName },
        primarySaleHappened: true,
        isMutable: true,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
}

updateSPLTokenMD().then().catch();

update docs: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/update
umi guides: https://developers.metaplex.com/guides/javascript/how-to-create-an-spl-token-on-solana

The Umi docs are focused on making JS clients - for tokens, the right Metaplex docs are https://developers.metaplex.com/guides/javascript/how-to-create-an-spl-token-on-solana

thanks bruh am gonna try it out now cheers mate
